# PXE Linux kernel line for Preseed

Tags: system-installation, pxe, preseed, edubuntu

I want to setup a Preseed for my Edubuntu 12.04 on my PXE Server, running PXE Linux
but I can't seem to figure out how to add the Preseed.

```
LABEL Install edUbutnu Junior 12.04 x86
        MENU LABEL edUbuntu Junior 12.04 x86
        KERNEL edubuntu/vmlinuz
        APPEND boot=casper netboot=ntf nfsroot=10.30.92.10:/images/isos/edubuntu initrd=edubuntu/initrd.lz preseed/url=http://10.30.92.10/edubuntu1204/juniorgrades.seed splash --

LABEL Install edUbutnu Senior 12.04 x86
        MENU LABEL edUbuntu Senior 12.04 x86
        KERNEL edubuntu/vmlinuz
        APPEND boot=casper netboot=ntf nfsroot=10.30.92.10:/images/isos/edubuntu initrd=edubuntu/initrd.lz preseed/url=http://10.30.92.10/edubuntu1204/seniorgrades.seed splash --
```

Answer (score 0):

Might you mean `netboot=nfs` rather than `netboot=ntf` ?

Correct these errors and try again.